# How to toggle color of a button by javascript in pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf

I don't know whether this forum is for PDF form related question or not. If it is not, then please let me know where to move this topic.

Anyway, I want to toggle the fillColor of a button by javascript of a PDF form. I want to change the button color to green if it is red and vice-versa. For this, I have written this code to action:

```
var f = event.target;
if(f.fillColor == color.red){
app.alert("Color is red");
f.fillColor = color.green;
}else{
app.alert("Color is not red");
f.fillColor = color.red;
}
```

But the action is not performing expectedly. Please let me know what is the wrong in my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript code as the MouseUp event of the button:

```
event.target.fillColor = color.green;
```

If you want it to change back and forth, use this code:

```
event.target.fillColor = (color.equal(color.blue, event.target.fillColor)) ? color.green : color.blue;
```

Comment: Sorry, This is a PDF form, not a html page.

Comment: OH your question was unclear. And this is not the related forum to post such questions

Comment: Post it in https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/bd-p/acrobat?page=1&sort=relevance&filter=all